# Why don't shared files show up in HGFS?

Tags: windows, vmware, sharing, file-sharing

Sharing files between my Guest Kubuntu OS and Host Windows has become a real headache.

So, far I have done the steps below:

**GUEST LINUX OS**

- VM -> Settings -> Options -> Shared Folders. And added my folder.
- Installed properly my VMware tools (I can drag and drop files so I am confident that it is installed)

**HOST WINDOWS OS**

- Shared the folder with everyone (to assure that there is no permit limitations with my files)

If I type *vmware-hgfsclient* in my guest OS, the folder I am sharing does appear. But when I check the `/mnt/hgfs folder`, it is empty.

I have gone through the VMware manual, and I am sure that I have followed their requirements.

I am really out of ideas. Does any one have a suggestion?

Answer (score 45):

Run this command:

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs/ -o allow_other -o uid=1000
```

It will magically show all shared folders in `/mnt/hgfs`.
(I had Ubuntu 16 VMWare running on a Windows 10 host)

[VMware documentation here](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html)

Comment: I noticed sometimes there is a delay (using VMware workstation 14).  And sometimes `/mnt/hgfs` is in use.  I created a new folder `/mnt/shares1` and got instant success.

Comment: It works, but it's not remounted after reboot.

Comment: working, thank you

Comment: @realtebo Just modify the entry that shows up in /etc/mtab and stuff it in /etc/fstab for a permanent mount. It will probably look like this:
`.host:/ /mnt/hgfs fuse.vmhgfs-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other 0 0`

Answer (score 32):

I had this exact problem. It turned out IT had installed some old version of VMWare tools with non-functioning vmhgfs kernel module.

My solution was to run the configuration with the clobber-kernel-modules setting to overwrite the existing vmhgfs module.

```
 sudo vmware-config-tools.pl -d --clobber-kernel-modules=vmhgfs
```

The -d selects all the defaults for you (remove it if you don't want the defaults).

Comment: bingo, I had the same issue, and running the command above solved it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Just want to mention that this worked for me with OSX as host, vmware Fusion running CentOS 6.4

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me with OSX as host and VM runnig Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: command not found error, i am using vmware workstation 12 an ubuntu 15.04

Comment: The -d alone was worth the vote.  Didn't know about that.

Comment: ubuntu16.04.3 failed:Unable to find the database file (/etc/vmware-tools/locations)

Answer (score 4):

`mount -t vmhgfs .host:/share /mnt/hgfs/` where *host* is the host you are connecting to *share* is the share name and */mnt/hgfs* is the mount point for the share in your system.

vmware-hgsclient will show you the available mounts, you still need to mount them with `vmware-hgfsmounter` or using the mount command above described.

If that does not work check if the module *vmhgfs* is loaded `lsmod | grep "vm."`

Comment: It gave me this answer. Host in share name must be ".host". Error: share name is invalid, aborting mount. _vmhgfs_ is not loaded, how can I load it? Thanks.

Comment: mkdir /mnt/hgfs/

Answer (score 2):

For me, it turned out that vmware-hgfsmounter was not installed (ubuntu 12.10). After installing that module, I was able to mount my share as descibed above

Comment: I have it installed in /usr/lib/vmware-tools/sbin64, but it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This was working for me on Ubuntu 18.04, but suddenly stopped working sometime in February/March 2019. What was needed to be done, was `sudo mkdir /mnt/hgfs`, as [that directory is being used by the vmware init script](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2869442#2869442).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I installed "Development Tools" and reinstalled VMware Tool.
Then I see the shared folder.

Host: Windows 7
Guest OS: CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue while working with Ubuntu 21.10 impish. Below is a complete solution guide for this shared folder issue.

## Pre-work

Make sure `open-vm-tools` (and `open-vm-tools-desktop` if you're using a desktop environment) are installed, and that you've rebooted after their installation.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Make sure you have a `/mnt/hgfs` directory made and empty. If not:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/hgfs
```

## Mounting

To mount the filesystem, run:

```
sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
```

The shared folders will now be in subdirectories of `/mnt/hgfs`

## Setting up auto-mounting

Add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
.host:/   /mnt/hgfs   fuse.vmhgfs-fuse    auto,allow_other    0   0
```

**Update**: based on extensive testing, the `auto` keyword seems to work fine. Prior versions suggested `noauto`. If you have trouble with `auto`, change to `noauto` and see below

### If using the `noauto` keyword, but you want automount

1. Create or edit the script `/etc/rc.local` (as root), and add the line:

   ```
   mount /mnt/hgfs
   ```
2. make sure `rc.local` is executable and owned by root:

   ```
   sudo chown root:root /etc/rc.local
   sudo chmod 0755 /etc/rc.local
   ```
3. enable the `rc.local` service in systemd:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
   ```
4. reboot

The `rc.local` script runs as the last step of startup, allowing the HGFS filesystem to mount *after* `open-vm-tools` services are running, which is required for successful operation.

Browse `/mnt/hgfs` at will.

***Ref :***

https://gist.github.com/darrenpmeyer/b69242a45197901f17bfe06e78f4dee3

> Unlike using VMWare Tools to enable Linux guest capabilities, the
> open-vm-tools package doesn't auto-mount shared VMWare folders.

Reference from official docs :
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1215135)

Comment: Thanks, @matigo for correction, I have updated the answer with essential parts from the reference link.